# Consumo de URL https IBPT

Tags: java, web-service, nfe, https

Preciso consumir a url nova da IBPT para fazer os calculos de impostos sem ficar importando tabelas.

A url é esta : [https://apidoni.ibpt.org.br/api/v1/produtos?token=...tMobi=un&valor=34000.00>in=sem](https://apidoni.ibpt.org.br/api/v1/produtos?token=...tMobi=un&valor=34000.00%3Ein=sem) gtin

Antes eu fazia apenas isso e pronto.

```
  HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOut);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String retorno = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        return retorno;
```

Agora teriei que criar sockets? Como é feito na nota fiscal?

Porque se eu tento conectar a essa url por este método dá erro 404.

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava na url, não tem que fazer socket para consultas IBPT. Basta usar um enconde de url onde terá espaços, por exemplo, na descrição do produto e na opção "sem gtin".

Ex: =Fiat%20Mobi%20Like%201.0%20CHASSI%209BD341A5XLY620671%20-%20QQS-4242&unidadeMedida=un&valor=34000.00&gtin=Sem%20Gtin

Answer (score -2):

```
    String token = "TOKEN";
    String cnpj = "CNPJ";
    String ncm = "27101932";
    String uf = "PB";
    String ex = "0";
    String descricao = "TESTE";
    String unidadeMedida = "UN";
    String valor = "5.38";
    String gtin = "SEM GTIN"; //informe o GTIN
    
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = null;
    try {
        String url = "https://apidoni.ibpt.org.br/api/v1/produtos?token="+token+"&cnpj="+cnpj+
                "&codigo="+ncm+"&uf="+uf+"&ex="+ex+"&descricao="+descricao+"&unidadeMedida="+
                unidadeMedida+"&valor="+valor+"&gtin="+URLEncoder.encode(gtin, "UTF-8");
        response = Unirest.get(url).asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(IBPT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    valorTributoImportado = response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("ValorTributoImportado");
    valorTributoNacional = response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("ValorTributoNacional");
    valorTributoEstadual = response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("ValorTributoEstadual");
    valorTributoMunicipal = response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("ValorTributoMunicipal");
    fonte = response.getBody().getObject().getString("Fonte");
    versao = response.getBody().getObject().getString("Versao");
    double total = valorTributoImportado+valorTributoNacional+valorTributoEstadual+valorTributoMunicipal;
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
    System.out.println("Valor aproximado dos tributos: "+Numero.DoubleToCurrecy(total));
    System.out.println("Fonte: "+fonte+", versao: "+versao);
```